# HTML code not dispalyed correctly with render()

Tags: reactjs

I'm retrieving data from an external source and description field contains some HTML code e.g.

```
<p>some text with <a hre="#">link</a></p>
```

When i render the value i'm getting it on screen exactly as posted above. How can i display plain text?

```
  return (
    <div className="col-md-8">
      <div className="details">
        <div>{title}</div>
        <div>{description}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Can you post the code surrounding the html?  I think it's likely you forgot to return the html somewhere...

Comment: updated initial post with render code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). It allows you to render raw html stored as a string:

```
function createMarkup() {
  const description = "<p>some text with <a hre="#">link</a></p>";
  return {__html: description};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go ahead and start using only Paragraph tags you will get plan text